# live wallpaper, frame animation, lags

Tags: java, android, animation, frame, lag

My frame animation lagging. Why is it lagging?

Code:

```
public class LiveWallpaperService extends WallpaperService {

    Bitmap mPic;
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public Engine onCreateEngine() {
        return new CubeEngine();
    }

    class CubeEngine extends Engine {

        private float mPosY, mPosX;

        private Matrix mMatrix = new Matrix();
        private int k = 1;
        private boolean mAnime = true;

        private boolean test;
        private static final int NUM_RES = 30;

        private final Runnable mDrawAnim = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
                    k++;
                    drawFrame();

                    if (i == 30) {
                        k = 1;
                    }

                }

            }

        };

        private boolean mVisible;

        CubeEngine() {

            Resources res = getResources();
            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_RES; i++) {
                int id = res.getIdentifier("boot_00" + (100 + (i + 1)),
                        "drawable", "com.example.dxd1");
                mPic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, id);

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

            super.onCreate(surfaceHolder);

            setTouchEventsEnabled(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mDrawAnim);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
            mVisible = visible;
            if (visible) {
            drawFrame();
            }else {
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(mDrawAnim);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                int width, int height) {
            super.onSurfaceChanged(holder, format, width, height);

            float w = mPic.getWidth();
            float h = mPic.getHeight();
            float s = width / (float) w;
            float s2 = height / (float) h;

            mMatrix.reset();
            mMatrix.setScale(s, s2);


        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            super.onSurfaceCreated(holder);

        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            super.onSurfaceDestroyed(holder);
            mVisible = false;
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mDrawAnim);
        }

        public void updateBG() {

            if (k == 1) {
                mPic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.boot_00101);

            }
            if (k == 2) {
                mPic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.boot_00102);

            }
            if (k == 3) {
                mPic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.boot_00103);

            }
            if (k == 4) {
                mPic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.boot_00104);

            }
            if (k == 5) {
                mPic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.boot_00105);

            }
            if (k == 6) {
                mPic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.boot_00106);

            }
            if (k == 7) {
                mPic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.boot_00107);

            }
            if (k == 8) {
                mPic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.boot_00108);

            }
            if (k == 9) {
                mPic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.boot_00109);

            }
            if (k == 10) {
                mPic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.boot_00110);

            }
            if (k == 11) {
                mPic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.boot_00111);

            }
            if (k == 12) {
                mPic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.boot_00112);

            }
            if (k == 13) {
                mPic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.boot_00113);

            }
            if (k == 14) {
                mPic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.boot_00114);

            }

            if (k == 15) {
                mPic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.boot_00115);

            }
            if (k == 16) {
                mPic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.boot_00116);

            }
            if (k == 17) {
                mPic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.boot_00117);

            }
            if (k == 18) {
                mPic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.boot_00118);

            }
            if (k == 19) {
                mPic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.boot_00119);

            }
            if (k == 20) {
                mPic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.boot_00120);

            }
            if (k == 21) {
                mPic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.boot_00121);

            }
            if (k == 22) {
                mPic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.boot_00122);

            }
            if (k == 23) {
                mPic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.boot_00123);

            }
            if (k == 24) {
                mPic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.boot_00124);

            }
            if (k == 25) {
                mPic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.boot_00125);

            }
            if (k == 26) {
                mPic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.boot_00126);

            }
            if (k == 27) {
                mPic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.boot_00127);

            }
            if (k == 28) {
                mPic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.boot_00128);

            }
            if (k == 29) {
                mPic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.boot_00129);

            }
            if (k == 30) {
                mPic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.boot_00130);

            }

        }

        void drawFrame() {
            final SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();

            Canvas c = null;

            c = holder.lockCanvas();
            if (c != null) {

                drawAnim(c);

            }

            if (c != null) {
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
            // Reschedule the next redraw
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mDrawAnim);
            if (mVisible && mAnime) {
                mHandler.postDelayed(mDrawAnim, 50);
            }

        }

        void drawAnim(Canvas c) {

            updateBG();

            c.drawBitmap(mPic, mMatrix, null);

        }

    }
```

Comment: I didn't test this code at all, but your `updateBG()` could definitely be fixed; why are you doing all of those `if` statements instead of using `switch`/`case`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decoding bitmaps on the draw thread is very very heavy, and will definitely result in lag. You can't just draw an animation with fullscreen bitmaps for every frame. You'll have to cache them (unlikely, since you would run out of ram with so much fullscreen bitmaps), or you have to draw the contents programmaticaly (so a dynamic generated image) or only use partial bitmaps/layers (aren't they called sprites?) and move those parts around.

I developed a app for a client with a fullscreen animated intro with bitmaps, and on most devices it wouldn't reach 5fps, while the (original) iphone version reached much more. I resorted to just using a h264 encoded movie (which has other compatibility problems). So, this way it's not going to work.

So, main question is, why are you using 30 bitmaps to draw something? Can't you use layers, so you use smaller bitmaps? Maybe animate them yourself? Why not even use a movie instead of manually animating? Are you using fullscreen images?

If you are not using fullscreen images, maybe implement some sort of pre-caching so you already have decoded 2 images to a bitmap before rendering, while keeping that cache updated.

Comment: The image to be smooth I need animation of 30 bitmaps in full screen. Im create wallpaper for tablets and if im use smaller bitmaps the images will be bad quality. How to use layers?

Comment: Layers are just bitmaps that you draw over eachother. So it depends on the bitmaps. If for example you have a circle moving around your images, then you could render the backgorund image and a small image of the circle on a manually specified position. But I am afraid you'll have to research yourself how other people create such wallpapers. I guess they don't use fullscreen bitmaps, but more dynamic generated stuff.